# Django: Use ugettext_lazy in templates

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, django-templates

Hello I want to know if I can use `ugettext_lazy as _` in the templates of django because I want to replace the tags of `{% trans %}` and `{% blocktrans %}` because I don't want to make the messages.

I want to do something like this:

```
<h1>_('hello')</h1>
```

Instead of this:

```
<h1>{% trans 'hello' %}</h1>
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean you "don't want to make the messages"!? That's how translation works. If you don't want to make messages, you can just provide everything in a single language & you don't have to worry about `ugettext` or `i18n`

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to call any function from a template that takes any arguments. You have to write either [tag or filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/#howto-custom-template-tags) but I would suggest you to stick with the `trans` block.

Answer (score 0):

I want to say that `<h1>_('hello')</h1>` this functionality not possible in django template.

but we have another way of like this with custom templatetag that support your way for translate string in template

```
{% some_tag _("Page not found") value|yesno:_("yes,no") %}
```

above added string will work as translation in django.

Read from django documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/translation/#string-literals-passed-to-tags-and-filters